# How did the Enterprise get to Qo'nos unopposed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

In *ST: Into Darkness* the *Enterprise* flew straight to Qo'nos  without a problem as it seems.

How is that possible especially if the Klingons posed a real threat to the Federation?

Comment: Was that Qo'nos?  I thought it was a Klingon influenced, but technically neutral/unclaimed planet.  A location the Enterprise could be in, even though what they were *doing there* was forbidden.

Comment: It is Qo'Nos they go to

Comment: @ZeissIkon they went directly to the klingon homeworld not a neutral planet (the later I could have seen, but the former I didn't get at all how the hell they went there unopposed......at least if there was any remaining threat from the klingons at all that is.

Comment: Okay.  Only seen the movie once.  Question isn't about where Big E was, but how they got there unchallenged, presumably through the heart of Klingon space.

Answer (score 2):

They did not:

> MARCUS: As part of our defensive strategy, 31 developed a new photon
> torpedo. (calls up hologram) Long range and untraceable, it would be
> invisible to Klingon sensors. I don't want you hurt, but I want to
> take him out. **You park on the edge of the Neutral Zone**, you lock onto
> Harrison's position, you fire, you kill him and you haul ass.

So the intention was to park on the edge of the neutral zona and use the torpedoes (which are long range) to reach Qo'nos.

Once they decide to change the plan the use a contraband cargo ship to get to Qo'nos. The Enterprise never makes it into Klingon space.

> SULU [OC]: Please have the trade ship we confiscated during the Mudd
> incident last month fuelled and flight ready. Captain Kirk is en route
> to you now.
>
> SPOCK: Ready to deploy, Captain.
>
> KIRK: Lieutenants, lose the red shirts. You are K'normian arms dealers. Put those on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Kirk and the crew knew at that point in the movie, no ship was capable of catching *Enterprise* while *Enterprise* was travelling at warp<sup>(1)</sup>.  They only considered opposition to be a possibility for the cargo ship's sublight travel to and from Qo'noS, and for the team's brief time on the planet's surface.  For the vulnerable stage of the mission, they relied on speed, stealth, and subterfuge --- and were promptly caught.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Inferred from a later scene, when *Enterprise* is on the run from *Vengeance*:

> CAROL: He's gonna catch up with us, and when he does, the only thing that's going to stop him destroying this ship is me, so you have to let me talk to him.
>
> KIRK: Carol, we're at warp. He can't catch up with us.
>
> CAROL: Yes, he can. He's been developing a ship that has advanced warp capabilities, and I
>
> SULU: Captain! I'm getting a reading I don't understand.
>
> (Vengeance is chasing Enterprise through the slipstream, sorry, warp space. Weapons are fired, causing a hull breach in Enterprise's starboard side. Then the nacelles are hit and Enterprise drops out of warp.)
>
> ---
>
> Transcript: [*Star Trek Into Darkness*](http://www.chakoteya.net/Extras/STintoD.html) (2013)

Comment: As far as I understood it was not the Enterprise being so fast, but instead that nobody can chase anyone THROUGH the warp (they can only arrive earlier/later/at the same time at the same location, not chasing them while at warp.

Comment: That's not true, there're numerous references in canon about following a warp trail. http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Warp_trail

Comment: This quote only says that it's an issue, not how it works.  It seems similar to how ships can't fire while cloaked unless they can, so I suspect that there might not be anything closer to an explanation.

Comment: Yeah, the examples from that web page are all from the Prime universe and don't agree with this declaration from the reboot universe, so that's frustrating.